# React Native - Can't place icon on top of image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

I'm trying to place an icon over an image, but all it's doing is pushing the image down the page.

Here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to place the blue back arrow on top of that image as you can see.

Here's what my markup looks like:

```
<ScrollView style={ styles.container }>
  <View style={ styles.coverImageContainer }>
    <Image
      style={ styles.coverImage }
      source={ require('./img.jpg') }
    >
      <View>
        <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" color="#4F8EF7" size={25} />
      </View>
    </Image>
  </View>
  ...
```

And here are my styles:

```
container: {
  backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
  flex: 1,
},

coverImageContainer: {
  backgroundColor: '#000',
},

coverImage: {
  width: null,
  height: 170,
  resizeMode: 'cover',
  opacity: 0.7,
  flex: 1,
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I get rid of the icon, the image displays how I want it to, but I would like the back button icon on top of it too. Here's what it looks like without the icon:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Position `Icon` component absolutely.

```
<Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" color="#4F8EF7" size={25} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 30, left: 10 }} />
```

Answer (score 2):

The StatusBar is always visible, even if you use `position:'absolute'; zIndex: 99999` on back button, the are 2 ways:

1. Remove status bar by adding `<StatusBar hidden={true}/>` inside a render
2. Add `marginTop: 22` for moving arrow a little downward

Comment: I would like the image to remain behind the status bar as it's doing in my updated question. That's part of the design, I just don't want it to be pushed down when I add an icon on top of it. Please see my updated question

Comment: @Thomas got it, i misunderstood the question, anyway Andreyco answer should help